# Copy from a workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am having issues developing this code. I was able to develop the code to copy new data from my workbook to an existing path but am running into issues when trying to retrieve data from the existing path work book.

The concept is that there is a workbook in my system that will be collecting data. The data comes from different users that are working on project information. Once they have completed the project this new information along with existing information gets uploaded back to the workbook collecting that data. The work book collecting the data will always have a defined path. The workbooks that users are working off of will be in multiple places across the system.

The below macro keeps failing on the "Organizer.Sheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select". I am unsure why.

"Organizer" is the local database the user will use.
"Partnumber_Vendor_File" is the local database the information is stored.

If you can see that this code could be developed better please let me know! :)

```
Sub Find_Partnumber_Vendor_File()

'   This sub is to open the partnumber_Vendor file to update the local database.

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Organizer As Workbook
    Set Organizer = Application.ActiveWorkbook


    Dim Partnumber_Vendor_File As Workbook
    Set Partnumber_Vendor_File = Workbooks.Open("S:\Supply Chain\PURCHASING\Forms and Templates\BOM Organizer\Partnumber_Vendor_File.xlsx")

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Could not open. Check path in VBA"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Partnumber_Vendor_File.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, partnumber to vendor database was already in use, try later"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim Data As Long
    Data = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:" & "D" & Data).Copy


    Organizer.Sheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select
    Range("A1:D1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Partnumber_Vendor_File.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you write `Organizer.Activate`, before the code that fails?

Comment: Hello Vityata,         Organizer.Activate had no affect.  The error occurred again on the Organizer.Sheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select. I even removed the "organizer." on Organizer.Sheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select.  Good thinking though! :)

Comment: `Organizer.Worksheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select`?

Comment: Still not working. It is coming up with a automation error.

Comment: Well. What you can actually do is to record a macro. Then select a few times the "Partnumber_Vendor_Database" sheet and check the code, that the macro recorder generates. Then put the code in your code. Check this as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270922/what-is-causing-automation-error-unspecified-error-on-worksheet-activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althoug it is easy to use, avoid `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet` and `Sheets(<Title of the Sheet.)`.

The problem with the first two is that is hard to tell if the activeworkbook is actually the workbook you are looking for, specially when there are more than 1 workbook open. To workaround this, one solution is the use the `Workbooks` object to select the correct work book by its NAME (property `CodeName`). The Same for the Sheets, change the REAL NAMES of the Sheets so you can properlly call them.

The third is basically the same principle. In general, do not use titles of Sheets as references, use the REAL NAME of the object. Use the Property window in the VBA code to change that.

The error may come from 2 situations:

1 - Your selected workbook is not the actual workbook you want to work on.

2 - The Sheet "Partnumber_Vendor_Database" had its title changed or miswritten.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Rdnoberga,  What you said definitely makes sense.  Due to this fill being a template that multiple users will copy, rename, and save in different folders of there department I thought by setting this as a object  as the active workbook it would make the most sense.       I thought by putting in the "Organizer." it would select the correct workbook.  If there is another way too get around this please let me know! :)    I changed the code from Organizer.Sheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select to Organizer.Sheets(2).Select. However this came up with a error stating "Automation Error".

Comment: Warren, try this: change the name of the sheet object entitled "Partnumber_Vendor_Database". This can be changed in the property window in the VBA Editor. See here: [link](http://imgur.com/a/MEskD). This way, you can change the name to Something like Vendor_DB and access it directly on your code. So, instead of using `Organizer.Sheets("Partnumber_Vendor_Database").Select` you can just type `Vendor_DB.Select`. Let me know if it worked out :)

Comment: Link is blocked at work. I will try to take a look tonight.