# IE excel vba to fetch data

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I need to fetch data from a website. The website content following tag, and I need to extract href attribute.

link rel='canonical' href='http://www.wingatecinci.com'

For this, I have written following code to extract href attribute in Excel

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Tester()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cano As String

    Range("A1").Value = "Cano"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    URL = "http://www.wingatecinci.com/"
    IE.navigate Url
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Cano = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("canonical")(i).innerHTML
    Range("A" & i + 2).Value = Cano
End Sub
```

But I did not get the success, and facing error see this screenshot
http://prntscr.com/kpy9dh
Can any one look into this and help me out??

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Please provide more information about what you're trying to do (including a sample of the HTML you're scraping, and desired output), and describe your problem. ("Did not get success" is not helpful.) Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and see "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**.  Also, here's a "perfect question" [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user. You can [edit] your question to clarify by adding more information.

Comment: Note that your code isn't going to compile at all because of the unneeded `,` comma in your `Dim` statement. Also there are undeclared variables. Adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules will help you identify undeclared variables and objects.

Comment: Please state what you are after. You have an i variable that has no value so if that is the correct element collection which index do you want from the collection? Showing the relevant html would help.

Comment: no such element in the given link except the hyperlink

Comment: Hey Karthick,
there is a element in the website

see below
'<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.wingatecinci.com'>

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wait in for the element and use a CSS attribute selector to target the attribute. This currently has a loop of 5 seconds to try and locate the element.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLink()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, ele As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.wingatecinci.com/"

        t = Timer
        Do While ele Is Nothing
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.querySelector("[rel='canonical']")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop
        If Not ele Is Nothing Then Debug.Print ele.href
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References:**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried the above code, but it is showing an error message, please see this screenshot for error https://prnt.sc/kqbfjj

Comment: Does it repeatedly produce this error? Works from my end just fine. If you repeatedly have this problem try Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: Yes, it is still showing the same error. 
I have applied Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium but still having same error.

can you please suggest any other option?

Comment: Maybe first to an Office [repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b). Then look through any articles on SO about this .e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270922/what-is-causing-automation-error-unspecified-error-on-worksheet-activate. Failing that, do you have an IT dept to work with?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines reference `i` as a variable:

```
Cano = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("canonical")(i).innerHTML
Range("A" & i + 2).Value = Cano
```

But you haven't set the value of `i` anywhere in your code. Did you mean to put this inside a loop perhaps?

---

Also the "tag" here is `<link>` - the `"canonical"` part is an *attribute* of that tag, so you need to further elaborate in your code to test for these:

```
For Each el In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("link")
    If el.hasAttribute("link") Then
        // do something with this element
    End If
Next
```