# My working macro stopped working (no changes were made)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that connects to a web-page, gets some info and displays it on a user form (for further actions):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim login As String, password As String
Dim waittime As String
Dim arrForms As Variant
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

LoadingForm.Show vbModeless
LoadingForm.lblLoading.Caption = "Loading..."

waittime = "0:00:02"
login = "lgn"
password = "passwrd"
txtEndDate.Value = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy")

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
'open login page
ie.navigate "my link (internal company database)"
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))

'if already logged in, skip
On Error GoTo Skip_login
ie.document.getElementById("_58_login").Value = login
ie.document.getElementById("_58_password").Value = password
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(0).Click
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))

Skip_login:
ie.navigate "my link (internal company database)"
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))

arrForms = GetListOfForms(ie) 'this is a function that reads the page,
'finds a table and converts its values to an array
'I tried to comment this line (maybe a bug in my function)
'but even without it the code does not work
For i = LBound(arrForms) To UBound(arrForms)
    FormsList.AddItem (arrForms(i))
Next i

'Log out and quit IE
ie.navigate "my link (internal company database)"
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))

ie.document.getElementById("sign-out").Click
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))
ie.Quit

LoadingForm.Hide

End Sub
```

It worked fine for a few days. It also worked today. But it stopped working for an unknown reason (it just says"automation error" without reference to an error in my code). I was using it, closed the user form, then clicked to start macro again and it does not work. I tried to open older backups - they stopped working too. I did not change anything (links, login/password, any other line of code).

My user form does not have any uncommon user controls. It has the following controls only: text fields, lables, frames, listbox, and buttons)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing "Automation error Unspecified error" on Worksheet\_Activate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270922/what-is-causing-automation-error-unspecified-error-on-worksheet-activate)

Comment: I tried adding references and removing listbox: did not help. Could it be because of such simple controls like buttons or textfields? I cannot remove them - they are 100% needed for my macro. Also tried adding DoEvents everywhere

Comment: Now I actually tried to remove ALL the controls - it did not help either. I left only several lines of code that create an IE object and then close it. This still gets "Automation error"

Comment: Perhaps the web page "my link (internal company database)" has changed?

Comment: No, I can access it manually. I tried the following: created new workbook and new empty module. There, I only entered two lines of code: "dim ie as object" and "set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")". And even this does not work and says "Automation error" (I added the needed references)

Comment: It may be that something on the website changend so your code doesn't work anymore. Go through your code step by step using F8 to find out which line causes the error.

Comment: It now has only two lines of code as per above :)

Comment: Does it work in a normal procedure (not in `UserForm_Initialize`)?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ no, it stopped working everywhere (I tested in an empty module of a new empty workbook)

Comment: Computer restarted?

Comment: I was working with code in Excel that was popping up instances of PowerPoint. During the course of debugging, I also inexplicably received the `Automation Error`. I figured I had some hung/unclosed Windows processes so I rebooted my workstation and the problem did not appear again. YMMV

Comment: Oh, did not even think of rebooting my PC was the problem - it is now fixed. Very sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Really? Helpdesk question number 1: *"Did you turn it off and on again?"*. What ever you are going to ask in your life … try that first. This will be every Helpdesk's first question (hopefully ;).